# How can I retrieve list of Wi-Fi hotspots in Mac application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, wifi

I need to programatically retrieve a list of nearest Wi-Fi hotspots(preferably using swift, but if it's not possible, objective-c will do) and I just don't get how can I do it. I have tried to search for samples, but the only one I found is outdated and doesn't run on *Xcode 6.3*. Any help will be great.

I'm now trying to use Swift code below, but it's not working, any tips?

```
var ind = CWInterface()

@IBAction func doer(sender: AnyObject) {

    var network:CWNetwork?
   var networks = ind.scanForNetworksWithName(nil, error: nil)
    for network in networks
   {
        print(network)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more googling and reading forums I realized what caused my Swift code to crash the app and I fixed the bug, here's working example:

```
var cwInterface: CWInterface = CWInterface(name: "en1")
    var netArray:[CWNetwork]=[]
    var testArray:[String]=[]
netArray = Array(cwInterface.scanForNetworksWithName(nil , error: nil)) as! [CWNetwork]
        var network=netArray[0]
        for network in netArray
        {
            testArray.append(network.ssid)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out and update the Apple project from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreWLANWirelessManager/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008921-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) (that you probably mentioned) with the help of this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreWLAN/Reference/CoreWLANTypes_header_reference/) to the current interfaces that apple exposes.

For example instead of using `kCWPHYMode11A` you use `kCWPHYMode11a`, instead of using `kCWSecurityModeWEP` you use `kCWSecurityWEP`. Try changing these two, then go to the definition of `kCWSecurityModeWEP` and, you'll see in the header all the corresponding elements that changed, thankfully you they have descriptive names so it's kind of straight forward to match. Keep in mind that some enums may have changed - like `CWSecurity`, so you need to search a little for the developer notes on these changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice, but I've found what bug in my swift code in the original post caused app to behave incorrectly and now it runs great, so there's no need to upgrade this old project